# Правильно ли реализовано потокобезопасное свойство?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть ли смысл в следующем коде:

```
object _sync = new object();
bool _property;
public bool MyProperty
{
        get
        {
            lock (_sync)
                return _property;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_sync)
                _property = value;
        }
    }
```

Какие подводные камни могут быть при чтении\записи этого свойства из нескольких потоков?

Comment: и чего вы там блочить для чтения собрались?

Comment: @teran, а разве чтение свойства безопасно? Например когда несколько потоков читают его, и несколько потоков его изменяют. Сути вопроса это не меняет.

Comment: Присвоение любого значения до 32 бит включительно потокобезопасно. 

Если нужно всегда иметь актуальное значение свойства, то есть если кто-то записал в него true, то в любом случае все читающие должны получить сразу актуальное значение, то можно использовать примитив синхронизации ReaderWriterLockSlim

Comment: Такая реализация бессмысленна.

Comment: @CasperSC: вы путаете потокобезопасность с атомарностью.

Comment: @VladD, я ничего не путаю, просто я не увидел в чём тут у автора проблема. Вижу тип bool, зачем ему тут потокобезопасность? Я предположил, что он боится, что два потока будут писать значения в поле класса и в какой-то момент времени в поле класса окажется для читающего потока неверное значение (то есть, к примеру, если бы там был long и два потока записли туда что-то и третий поток бы в это время считал значение, что по идее могло привести к тому, что он прочитает не то, что туда запишет один из тех ранее упомянутых двух потоков).

Comment: @CasperSC: Атомарность ещё не гарантирует, что изменения, сделанные в одном потоке, будут «видны» в другом потоке. Поэтому того, что значение влазит в регистр, не достаточно, чтобы говорить о потокобезопасности.

Comment: @VladD, точно, вы правы. Чтобы всё-таки работал вариант без lock'a, нужно поле `bool _property` поменить ключевым словом volatile. Надеюсь, сейчас я ничего не путаю :)

Comment: @CasperSC: Да, volatile тоже подойдёт, именно так.

Answer (score 3):

Реализация технически верна.

Но.

Вы не должны думать о потокобезопасности в терминах отдельных свойств объекта. Потокобезопасность — свойство всего объекта, и всех определённых на нём операций. К примеру, если у вас есть свойство `Age` и свойство `IsUnderage`, которое должно равняться `true` тогда и только тогда, когда `Age < 18`. Если вы сделаете потокобезопасными оба свойства по отдельности, между установкой первого и второго останется момент, в который они несогласованы — таким образом, ваш класс *как целое* всё ещё не потокобезопасен.

Таким образом, вы должны определить ваши сценарии использования (например — вызов публичных методов), и обеспечить потокобезопасность этих сценариев.

Comment: Именно поэтому в стандартной библиотеке потокобезопасны только статические свойства/методы, но не свойства/методы экземпляров?

Comment: @Андрей: Да. А также потому, что у юзера логической единицей может быть пара из нескольких классов, и внутренним объектом одного класса для синхронизации не обойтись.